# AppleScript to 'Bring All Hidden and Minimized Apps to Front'?

Tags: applescript

Have been searching for an hour. I am halfway through, but not getting very far.

Does anyone know what code to use to 'Bring All Hidden and Minimized Apps to Front'?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one window can be *frontmost*, at a time, however the following AppleScript *code* will unhide and un-minimize all windows.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set the visible of every process to true
    do shell script "killall -HUP Dock"
end tell
```

Comment: Awesome. Just to make sure, killing all the dock isn't an issue at all for any application (bugs, problems, etc; not that it doesn't work)?

Comment: No, it shouldn't.  I've used `killall -HUP Dock` for 10 years and never had issues with any application because of doing so.

Comment: Nope. Kill just sends a signal to a process, and HUP is a signal to tell the process to reload